# Divide a composite number

Tags: prime-numbers

Any hint for this demonstration?

Show that if $\displaystyle n$ is a composite (positive integer) number it has a divider that is less or equal to $\displaystyle \sqrt {n}$.

Comment: Suppose $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are primes dividing $n$. If both of them are greater than $\sqrt{n}$, then $p_{1} \times p_{2} > \sqrt{n} \times \sqrt{n} = n$. Contradiction.

Comment: If $n$ is a positive integer, then $1\le \sqrt n$, and $1$ is a divisor of every integer -- no matter if $n$ is composite or not.

Comment: Many thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: We know that divisors come in pairs (e.g. $3 \mid 12$ since $3\cdot 4 = 12$, this also yields $4 \mid 12$). What happens if such a pair of divisors are *both* greater than $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: We don't even need to know that divisors come in pairs _in general_ -- the "$n$ is composite" assumption says that we _have_ such a pair $n=ab$.